# What happened to Eleven at the end of season 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

How did Eleven lose her powers in *Stranger Things* season 3?

If it is from pain, then it is not consistent because there would have been more pain during the event than after the event.

If it is from the parasite, then the ability to remove said parasite should not be available either.

Comment: It seems really hard to say at this point. On one hand, the bite/parasite/Flayer could of maybe absorbed her ability, or it could of blocked that part of her mind that allows her access it (Remember, when it was KINETICALLY connected to Will, it made him feel bad/irritated. Maybe it's connected to her now?), and/or she may have burned her powers out, since we know from before she needs to "recharge" and she used her powers A LOT this season.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few theories floating around and you're right that the ability to remove the parasite should have gone as well. If you remember when she removes the parasite she releases enough energy to shatter the glass behind her. It may be that she has reached her limit, or that she has worn the power down and that it needs to replenish. There is also the theory that her powers are directly linked to the mindflayer and the upside down, with the gate now closed again (at least in Hawkins) it may be she no longer has the abilities.

Her powers are also directly linked to her emotions, her losing Hopper together with her using them a lot may have worn her out completely and they are lying dormant until she really needs them.

Comment: It's a good answer - I don't agree with "with the gate now closed again (at least in Hawkins) it may be she no longer has the abilities." 1) the gate was closed before 2) She can't move the car while the gate is still open other than that I agree with the rest

Comment: @Mike if she became telekinetic with the Mind Flayer, which there seems to be evidence because it knew where she was, then perhaps that theory works, because it now relies on where the MF is, where as before it didn't, because it wasn't psychically attached?!

Comment: @Mike the gate was closed, but as Alexei says, it was healing, so there may have still been a connection (if we assume this is how she has her powers). However, this theory relies on there being a tear before El was in the lab with Brenner at the start, after all we are led to believe that El opened the gate with her abilities implying she had the abilities before access to the upside down was available.